# DS1307 RTC conflicts with DS18B20

Tags: shields, lcd, sd-card, temperature-sensor

I'm working on a project to output the temperature from a DS18B20 to a 16x2 LCD while logging the temperature to a CSV file using the Adafruit Data Logging Shield. I keep getting this error when verifying the code:

```
RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp.o: In function `RTC_DS1307::now()':
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:252: undefined reference to 'Wire'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:252: undefined reference to 'Wire'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:252: undefined reference to 
'TwoWire::beginTransmission(int)'RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp.o: In function 'TwoWire::write(int)':
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Resources/Java/libraries/Wire/Wire.h:72: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::write(unsigned char)'
RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp.o: In function 'RTC_DS1307::now()':
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:254: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::endTransmission()'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:256: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::requestFrom(int, int)'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:257: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::read()'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:258: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::read()'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:259: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::read()'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:260: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::read()'
/Users/g/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:261: undefined reference to 'TwoWire::read()' RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp.o:/Users/grafton/Documents/Arduino/libraries/RTClib-master/RTClib.cpp:262: more undefined references to 'TwoWire::read()' follow
```

When I comment `RTC_DS1307 RTC;` in the code (below) these errors go away, but of course I get errors related to an undefined RTC. I'm a newbie cobbling together code from various sources, so any help is greatly appreciated. Code follows:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
#include <SD.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
const int chipSelect = 10;
File tempLog;
RTC_DS1307 RTC;

LiquidCrystal lcd(6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12);

void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(9600);
   while (!Serial) {
    ; 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  //         ----------------  
  lcd.print("Current temp (F)");
   sensors.begin();
   }

Serial.print("Initializing SD card...");
  pinMode(SS, OUTPUT);

  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Initialization done.");

tempLog = SD.open("templog.txt", FILE_WRITE);  
if (! tempLog) {
  Serial.println("Error opening templog.txt");
  while(1);
}
char filename[] = "LOGGER00.CSV";
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    filename[6] = i/10 + '0';
    filename[7] = i%10 + '0';
    if (! SD.exists(filename)) {
      // only open a new file if it doesn't exist
      tempLog = SD.open(filename, FILE_WRITE);
      break;  // leave the loop!
    }

  Serial.print("Writing to: ");
  Serial.println(filename);
  tempLog.println("Data Logging File");
  tempLog.println("Date,Temp(F)");
  } 
} 

void loop() {
  sensors.requestTemperatures();
  float temperature = sensors.getTempFByIndex(0);
  lcd.setCursor(6, 1);
  lcd.print(temperature);
  Serial.println(temperature);
  //-----------------------------------------------------------

String dataString = "";

//date time stuff-------------------------------------------

DateTime now = RTC.now();
  // log time
// tempLog.print(now.unixtime()); // seconds since 1/1/1970
//  tempLog.print(", ");
  tempLog.print('"');
  tempLog.print(now.year(), DEC);
  tempLog.print("/");
  tempLog.print(now.month(), DEC);
  tempLog.print("/");
  tempLog.print(now.day(), DEC);
  tempLog.print(" ");
  tempLog.print(now.hour(), DEC);
  tempLog.print(":");
  tempLog.print(now.minute(), DEC);
  tempLog.print(":");
  tempLog.print(now.second(), DEC);
  tempLog.print('"');

  tempLog.print(",");
  tempLog.print(temperature);
  tempLog.print(",");
  delay(500);

tempLog.println(dataString);
tempLog.flush();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTC library requires the `Wire` library. Just put `#include <Wire.h>` in front of the line `#include "RTClib.h"`

Comment: I have tried to simply `#include <Wire.h>` in RTClib.h, rather than putting `#include <Wire.h>` above `#include "RTClib.h"` in my sketch, but this does not work.  Do you know why?

Comment: That indeed doesn't work. I don't know the reason; sorry.